# Using the Splunk SDK for C#, why is oneshot search ignoring the set time range?

Tags: c#, search, time, sdk, range

I have an odd problem with setting time range for oneshot search. I set time range for my oneshot search, but results are just first found on server matching query. It seems like oneshot is just ignoring time range.

I've read:

How to run searches and jobs using the Splunk SDK for C# -
http://dev.splunk.com/view/csharp-sdk/SP-CAAAEQG

Service.SearchOneShotAsync Method -
http://docs.splunk.com/DocumentationStatic/CshrpSDK/2.1.1/Splunk.Client/html/a5323948-7506-ad15-6f04-7a95b70e616d.htm

JobArgs Class -
http://docs.splunk.com/DocumentationStatic/CshrpSDK/2.1.1/Splunk.Client/html/7dc4e71d-1ed7-4eb1-5a10-183d7663da26.htm

Time modifiers for search -
http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.0.3/SearchReference/SearchTimeModifiers

but after hours of tests and experiments - nothing.

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
         {
             var connectArgs = new ServiceArgs
             {
                 Host = "myip",
                 Port = 8089,
                 Scheme = "https"
             };

             Splunk.Service service = new Splunk.Service(connectArgs);
             service.Login("login", "password");

             var oneshotSearchArgs = new Splunk.Client.JobArgs();
             oneshotSearchArgs.EarliestTime = "2015-08-23 13:00";//textBoxOD.Text + "T" + textBoxODG.Text + ":00.000";
             oneshotSearchArgs.LatestTime = "2015-08-23 14:00";//textBoxDO.Text + "T" + textBoxDOG.Text + ":00.000";
             String oneshotSearchQuery = "search query *" + textBox1.text + "* | head 500";

             var outArgs = new JobResultsArgs
             {
                 OutputMode = JobResultsArgs.OutputModeEnum.Xml,
                 Count = 0,
             };

             try
             {
                 using (var stream = service.Oneshot(oneshotSearchQuery, outArgs))
                 {
                     using (var rr = new ResultsReaderXml(stream))
                     {
                         string raw = "_raw";

                         foreach (var @event in rr)
                         {
                             wynik += "EVENT:" + Environment.NewLine;
                             foreach (string key in @event.Keys)
                             {
                                 if (key.Contains(raw))
                                 {   
                                     wynik += "   " + key + " -> " + @event[key] + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being so late with an answer. I landed into the same issue.

The **reason** that your OneShot search ignores the time range is because it does not take one. (I did not come across any documentation to do so)

To overcome this issue, I tried the [2.X SDK for C#](http://dev.splunk.com/view/csharp-sdk-pcl/SP-CAAAEYY#oneshot). It fixed the issue.

You can use the 2.X version in 3 steps:

1. Setting up Service parameters. (host, port etc.)
2. Authenticating the Service.
3. Setting up parameters for the OneShot job and executing it.

You can find the NuGet package "**Splunk PCL Client for .Net**" in NuGet library [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Splunk.Client/).

Here is a sample code:

```
// Setting up Service parameters
Service _splunkService = new Service(Scheme.Https, "your-api-or-ip", 8089);

// Authenticating
await _splunkService.LogOnAsync("username", "password");

// Setting up parameters for the OneShot job and executing it
var query = "your search query";
var oneShot = new JobArgs();
oneShot.EarliestTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-2).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-2).TimeOfDay; //"2015-09-12T12:00:00.000-07:00";
oneShot.LatestTime = "your latest time";

using (var stream = await _splunkService.SearchOneShotAsync(query, 0, oneShot))
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var result in stream)
        {
            var rawValue = Convert.ToString(result.GetValue("_raw"));
            if (rawValue != null)
            {
                // do something.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure the 'await' parts go inside an async method.